# how to get data by clicking on item from listview that created dynamic?

Tags: jquery

i created a dynamic list view and i want to get the data from the line in the listview that i click on (the data is displayed on the listview, so the 'append' works perfect) , i get "undefind" when i click and try to get tha data into "x" and i don't understand why!

my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_parsed.Categories.length; i++){
        var cars= json_parsed.Categories[i];


        $('#categoryList').append($('<li   data-categoryId = cars.car_name>').html(' <a href="#"  onclick = "temp()" >'+cars.car_name+</a>'));
}


function temp () {
   var x = $(this).data('categoryId');  
   alert (x);   
};
```

thanks Ahead

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery you can bind `onclick` events like below.

```
$('#categoryList').on('click', 'li', function () {
    var x = $(this).data('categoryId');
    alert(x);
});
```

**Full Code:** (Fixed couple of stuff in your for loop)

```
var cars;
for (var i = 0; i < json_parsed.Categories.length; i++){
   cars = json_parsed.Categories[i];
   $('#categoryList').append('<li data-categoryId="' + cars.car_name + '"><a href="javascript:void(0)" >' +cars.car_name + '</a>');
}    

$('#categoryList').on('click', 'li', function () {
    var x = $(this).data('categoryId');
    alert(x);
});
```

---

**Edit:**

> thanks but its doesn't works... i add my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mici123/7aMke/13/)! thanks Ahead!

You missed to mention that you are using jQuery version 1.6.4.

Anyways Change the click handler like below,

```
$('#categoryList').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    var x = $(this).data('categoryid');
    alert(x);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7aMke/15/)

Comment: thanks but its doesn't works...
i add my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mici123/7aMke/13/)!

thanks Ahead!

Comment: @user1241167 Check my edits and let me know..  Also take some time to read how this website works.. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: thank you so much its was very helpful, and i will read how to use in this website

Answer (score 0):

You need to use live event i.e. an eventHandler that will bind to element those are not created at page load, but will create later ie. upcoming.

```
// delegate to #categoryList if it already in DOM in page load

$('#categoryList').on('click', 'li', function() {
   var x = $(this).data('categoryId');  
   alert(x);
});
```

Comment: I would delegate to `#categoryList` instead of `body`

Answer (score 0):

Live has been the traditional way to handle binding dynamic content. However, jQuery recommends using on() for jQuery 1.7+. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Example:

```
$('element').on('click', function(){//Do something});
```